# losing context with replace

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

In QooxDoo I have a problem with this code

```
html2plain : function (html) {
     html = html.replace(/<(S*?)[^>]*>.*?|<.*?\/>/g,  function( tag )
     {
          return this.pushHashtag(tag.toUpperCase());
      } );
      return( html );
 },
```

when it comes to the line

```
return this.pushHashtag(tag.toUpperCase());
```

there is no context for the variable `this` and the function `pushHashtag` becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve that, is by binding 'this' to the function.
To do that, you need to change the anonymous function as following (you should send this function to the replace method):

```
function(tag) {
  return this.pushHashtag(tag.toUpperCase());
}.bind(this)
```

and now, inside this function, 'this' will refer to the "right" 'this'